# What characters can apply elements to others?

Tags: genshin-impact

<sub>*Previously titled: How do I remove elements inflicted by Ley Line Disorders?*</sub>

Many domains have a Ley Line Disorder which takes effect so long as you're inflicted with an element. I know that I can remove an element by triggering an elemental reaction.

I've tried setting down Xiangling's Guoba, which works fine in grassy areas, but domains are full of stone. Is there a consistent way to remove elements, and thus the Ley Line debuffs?

Comment: I've noticed that elements apply to a single character, so swapping characters can mitigate the effects. Perhaps you have to cause a reaction?

Answer (score 4):

Aldrin Dino is right -- these disorders may be removed by reactions. A number of characters can produce reactions on themselves, but more interesting are characters that can produce reactions on others; this is done by applying elements while off-field. Within the game's terminology, the act of applying an element is called *imbuing*.<sup>1</sup>

Consistent ways of triggering imbuement, especially ones with no side effect, are called *cleanses* by the community. For example, Jean's elemental burst is usually considered a cleanse, since the Swirl reaction has no negative side effect. In contrast, Barbara's elemental skill is not considered a cleanse, since Frozen and Electro-Charged are both disruptive.

When an imbuement happens, it either lasts for some duration, or applies for a single tick. In this post, I'm using *momentary* to refer to the latter.

The party imbuement effects are:

- **Barbara**'s elemental skill **Let the Show Begin** momentarily applies **Wet** to the active character when it heals, once every ~4.75 seconds.
- **Bennett**'s elemental burst **Fantastic Voyage** continuously imbues the active character with **Pyro** when standing within its created *Inspiration Field*.
- **Jean**'s elemental burst **Dandelion Breeze** continuously imbues the active character with **Anemo** when standing within its created *Dandelion Breeze*.
- **Xinyan**'s elemental skill **Sweeping Fervor** creates a persistent shield. Upon activation, it imbues Xinyan with Pyro. Additionally, and not mentioned in its description, when switching characters, it also imbues the new character with Pyro.

The self-imbuement effects are:

- **Beidou**'s elemental skill **Tidecaller**, when held, creates a shield. Activating this shield imbues Beidou with **Electro**.
- **Diona**'s elemental skill **Icy Paws** creates a shield on-hit; when the shield is created, it momentarily imbues Diona with **Cryo**. However, if Diona is **Wet**, she will not self-inflict **Freeze**.
- **Xingqiu**'s elemental skill **Guhua Sword: Fatal Rainscreen** applies **Wet** to Xingqiu.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The terminology is inconsistent. When the element being imbued is Hydro, the game uses the term "applies Wet" instead of "imbues Hydro".</sub>

<sub>Rarely, the game instead uses the construction "applies the *X* element."</sub>

<sub>Occasionally, the game uses the term *infuse* instead; for example, Diona's elemental skill claims it "will infuse Diona with Cryo." The term *infuse* is usually applied to a character's weapon, to indicate converting its attacks from Physical to some form of Elemental damage; for example, Diluc's elemental burst causes his weapon "to be infused with Pyro."</sub>

Answer (score 3):

There are some characters in the game that can inflict elemental status on themselves like Barbara and Beidou. You can also try getting hit by the enemy with elemental attack like Slime or Treasure Hoarders to trigger elemental reaction but you will also take damage along with the elemental reaction.