# How can I reliably apply an element to Sayu's Fuufuu Windwheel?

Tags: genshin-impact

I'm currently trying to make a build that relies on Sayu's Fuufuu Windwheel state to create elemental reactions (for example, using Furina's Salon Members in Ousia state to apply Hydro and using Raiden's Eye of Stormy Judgment to apply Electro with Sayu's Fuufuu Windwheel).

This got me thinking: How can I reliably apply an element to Sayu's Fuufuu Windwheel? So far I know that Raiden's Eye of Stormy Judgment can be used to apply Electro, but what about the other elements?

Comment: I guess you'll need a persistent application of the element to roll through. Things like Mona's E or Kokomis E, or skills & bursts with an aoe, like Chongyuns E or Rosarias Q. Something which applies off-field

Comment: @Neon1024 And hope that you don't get infused with something else before you can infuse yourself with you chosen element. Good luck if you are fighting some consecrated beasts trio

Comment: Yeah, I think that goes for any swirl. Like trying to cast Sucrose Q for hydro, and hit some burning grass!

Comment: @Neon1024 yep, that is why I assumed the OP was looking for ways to avoid that. To put it into context, in regards to self infusion I would expect Barbara healing to work better than Mona since it applies hydro to the character.

Comment: So the answer is this https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376726/what-characters-can-apply-elements-to-others

Comment: Not really. Some of those characters can't apply the different elements to others, and some are wrong. There is also the important part of the question: reliability. I'm doing my own tests, but there are characters I don't so I can't test them.